# How to include symbols in title hrefs?

Tags: formatting, hyperref, symbols, tex-core, moderncv

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  

% personal data
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\phone[mobile]{\texttt{+}1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX}
\email{X@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/X/}
\homepage{X.github.io}         

\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1,colorlinks=false,linkbordercolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
}


    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see the blue outline is only around the words, and not the symbols. How can the symbols be included in the href?